# How to use a macro as the point arguments of both pspicture and \psframe?

Tags: pstricks

I forgot the rule to use `\expandafter` such that `\rect` can be used as the point arguments of both `psframe` and `pspicture`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\rect{(-3,-3)(3,3)}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top]\rect
    \psframe[linecolor=red]\rect
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Could you review it once more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSTricks expects

```
\begin{pspicture}[<options>]
```

to be followed by explicit coordinates. Thus `\rect` must be expanded before TeX starts looking to `\begin`.

```
\newcommand{\expandcoord}[2]{%
  \expandafter\expandcoordaux\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\expandcoordaux[2]{#2#1}
```

Then you can say

```
\expandcoord{\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top]}{\rect}
  \expandcoord{\psframe[linecolor=red]}{\rect}
\end{pspicture}
```

The main problem here is that `\expandafter` only jumps over *one* token, so an indirect way has to be taken. This, of course, will break `auto-pst-pdf` or similar packages.

Comment: Is it possible no to use `\expandcoordaux` but merge it into a single `\expandcoord`?

Comment: @HiggsBoson No. There is no primitive method for jumping over a braced group, so in a way or the other auxiliary macros must be employed. It wouldn't be too difficult to extend PSTricks so that `\begin{pspicture}[<options>]` accepts to be followed by "implicit coordinates"; however, doing it for all PSTricks commands such as `\psframe` would require extensive work.